# Nested loop Excel VBA - Shiftleft

Tags: vba, excel

I have a new program I am trying to create. I imported a csv file, and the data needs cleaned up. The first row has the correct headings, while there are some mismatches with what should be assigned to the column labels.

for example:
Correct row should be:

```
A         B     C      D
bxxxxxxx1 1994  7890   main
```

incorrect row(s) for example:

```
bxxxxxxx1 bxxxxxxx2 1994 1995 7890 7891  main main
bxxxxxxx1 bxxxxxxx2 bxxxxxxx3 bxxxxxxx4 1994 1995 1996 1997 7890 7891 7890 7891 main main main main
bxxxxxxx1 bxxxxxxx2 bxxxxxxx3 1994 1995 1996 7890 7891 7892 main main main
bxxxxxxx1....bxxxxxxxn 1994....yearn...7890...789n...main1....mainn
```

So the incorrect rows provide the b value multiple times, followed by their respective values, which offsets all of the rows with multiple b values. So I want to remove the bxxxxxxx2, 1995, 7891 and 2nd main, retaining the rest (shifting everything to the left to align with the column headers)

Code I have currently:

```
Sub bibcheck()
    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim n As Integer
    bibfound = 0

    For i = 3 To 9
        n = 0
        For j = 2 To 9
            Set Cel = Cells(i, j)

            If Cel Like "b*#" Or Cel Like "b*?" Then
                n = n + 1
                '  MsgBox n  :'to verify record is found
                Cel = ""    'Clear the bib record found


            'Insert new code
            'Use each n created per row to create a new loop for shifting to the  left
            'skip a value, then use n again to delete that many cells to the right, continuously shifting blanks to the left.

            Else  
            End If 
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How many columns of data *should* there be? In your example you have 4, but the code looks like you're expecting 9. Is that always the case, 9 columns would be correct?

Comment: The examples I'm using for I = 3 to 0 and j = 2 To 9 are arbitrary values to test out each row and column, to make sure that when I use the MsgBox, it prints out the value I'm expecting (I'm not great a programming). In reality, there are up to 7 columns that would include bxxxxxx whatever, and roughly 10,000 rows of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you asked:

```
Sub bibcheck()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastclm As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim oArr(1 To 4) As Variant
Dim t As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

With ws
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To lastrow
        lastclm = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        j = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, lastclm)), "b*")
        t = 1
        For j = 1 To lastclm Step j
            oArr(t) = .Cells(i, j).Value
            t = t + 1
        Next j
        .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, lastclm)).ClearContents
        .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 4)).Value = oArr
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: It does look like the 1st row was repeated and mixed with the second row.

Comment: I was a like confused about your example until I seen that you expanded the data to include a third set of data.  I would think that if this was the case that you should produce an extra row.  In any case it does work on the OP's dataset. +1

Comment: Can the above be modified to not divide by 4, because what if you don't have something divisible by 4? Is there a simple way to modify the loop to find the "b" values and clearcontents, as well as shift based on number of b values found, plus remove their respective data cells?

Comment: If there is not always four data points per "b" values then how do you know which data points belong to which "b"?  By your example all "b" have 4 data points.  For example if there are 3 "B" but only 2 years in the second data point there will never be any way for Excel to know which points to remove and which to keep.  There must always be a pattern or it does not work.

Comment: The columns of data actually extend from A:AE. I was providing a snippet of the pattern, to figure out a method to remove those values. So the correct values should go A:AE, whereas for instance, I have a row with 4 b values starting extending to BR.

Comment: okay then you have an variable number of data points but every "b" has the same number of datapoints in each row?

Comment: @TravisCowart see edit.  You may need to refresh the screen.  Next time please enunciate that the data may contain more data points than what is shown and that 4 was just for ease of clarification.  We cannot guess your intentions.  Also, if this works, remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: It's so close, but for some reason, oArr keeps repeating values and the next row may contain values from the previous.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125744/discussion-between-travis-cowart-and-scott-craner).

Comment: Thank you Scott. I finally figured out what was happening. The oArr was collecting the values as an array for each row, but it was not storing the blank cells as values. So I replaced all blank cells through BR with dashes, and ran the sub again. Works perfect.